# Thunderbird for ubuntu strange downloading

Tags: thunderbird

Screen shot of Thunderbird:

[image: Screen shot of thunderbird]

Moreover, it is now saying me downloading 44 of 19, while it just had downloaded all the inbox yesterday and there is no new email in my mailbox since then. (I checked in browser, no email)

Why is this happening? :(

I also asked a question about touchpad never answered by anyone :(

Comment: Does general reading and sending emails work as expected? Also, are you using IMAP or POP3 email?

Comment: I am using IMAP and yes it is sending emails and receiving as well. 
But I am waiting for its completion of download so that I may disconnect!